# Ternary Operator in JSX - Alternative?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I've found myself doing a lot of if-else conditions in React recently, but not actually needed anything on the else:

```
{node.tags ?
  <div className="tags"> {
    node.tags.map(e =>
      <p key={e}>{e}</p>
    )}
  </div> :
  <></>
}
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this, or is it the standard?

I was thinking about doing it in a function - but I'm not sure what alternatives there are:

```
const getTags = (node) => {

  if (!node.tags) {
    return;
  }

  return (
    <div className="tags"> {
      node.tags.map(e =>
        <p key={e}>{e}</p>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: "{node.tags && <whatever />}"

Comment: When in doubt check the docs [React Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Comment: I suggest to return null instead of <></> in ternary to avoid useless rendering.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, you can simplify this to:

```js
{node.tags &&
  <div className="tags"> {
    node.tags.map(e =>
      <p key={e}>{e}</p>
    )}
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Ah, okay. I've seen that about a few times but never really thought about what it was. What is that called?

Comment: It’s called “conditional rendering.”

Comment: @Oyyou It's called "logical and". That said: if you're doing this a "lot", you're probably missing some refactoring.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use `&&` for this purpose as the following:

```
{
  node.tags &&
  <div className="tags">
     {
         node.tags.map(e => <p key={e}>{e}</p>)
     }
  </div>  
}
```

You can read more about `&&` at [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) documentation. Especially the [Inline If with Logical && Operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) section which states:

> You may embed expressions in JSX by wrapping them in curly braces. This includes the JavaScript logical `&&` operator. It can be handy for conditionally including an element.

Answer (score 1):

I usually create a `ShowHide` component for all conditionals and a `map-function` for `Arrays`:

```js
const ShowHide = ({show, children}) => show && children

const Tag = ({tag}) => <p>{tag}</p>

const mapTagsToJSX = tags => tags && tags.map(tag => (<Tag key={tag} tag={tag} />))

const Tags = ({tags}) => (
    <div>
      <ShowHide show={tags}>
          {mapTagsToJSX(tags)}
      </ShowHide>
      <ShowHide show={!tags}>
        loading tags...
      </ShowHide>
    </div>
  )
  
const useTags = () => {
  const [tags, setTags] = React.useState(null)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setTags([1,2,3])
    }, 1000)
  }, [])
  return tags;
}

const App = () => {
 const tags = useTags()
 return (<Tags tags={tags}/>)
}

const root = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render(<App />, root)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Good Luck...